# PHP - Generar array multidimensional

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

desde un controlador en laravel intento generar un array con esta estructura, **Pregunta**

```
Name
```

Y luego las respuestas de cada pregunta (relación 1 a N) tienen esta estructura

```
uuid
created_at
updated_at
```

Y estoy intentando generar un array con esta forma

```
[
{
    "name": "name random",
    "answers": [
        {
            "uuid": "x1",
            "created_at": "2020-09-05T07:51:43.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-05T07:51:43.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "x2",
            "created_at": "2020-09-05T07:51:43.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-05T07:51:43.000000Z"
        },
    ]
},
}



    $formIds = ['1','2'];

    $formAnswersArray = [];

    foreach ($formIds as $formId) {

        $form = Form::where('id',$formId)->first();

        $formArray = [
            'name' => $form->name,
        ];

        array_push($formAnswersArray,$formArray);

        $formAnswers = FormAnswer::where('form_id',$formId)->get();

        $answersArray = [];

        foreach ($formAnswers as $formAnswer) {
            $formArray['answers']['uuid'] = $formAnswer->uuid;
            $formArray['answers']['created_at'] = $formAnswer->created_at;
            $formArray['answers']['updated_at'] = $formAnswer->updated_at;
        }

        array_push($formAnswersArray,$formArray);

    }
```

El código que tengo es este, el array resultante que me da es este (que no es válido)

```
[
{
    "name": "name random 1",
},
{
    "name": "name random 1",
    "answers": {
        "uuid": "91746cf7-6a48-48d8-8ea4-eab08298b425",
        "created_at": "2020-09-05T07:51:43.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-05T07:51:43.000000Z"
    }
},
{
    "name": "name random 2",
},
{
    "name": "name random 2",
    "answers": {
        "uuid": "91746d1a-9d88-41b6-9216-ca1dedb38d9e",
        "created_at": "2020-09-05T07:52:06.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-05T07:52:06.000000Z"
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de generar un array a través de dos tablas relacionales,  de la forma como tu la tienes de 1 -> N es de la siguiente forma (Hay muchas otras):

En el controladores genero la consulta de esta manera (Ver comentarios en el código):

```html
<?php
public function index()
 {
      $consulta = User::select(
          'users.name',
          'answers.uuid',
          'answers.created_at',
          'answers.updated_at',
      )
         //Establezco la relación en el join entre las dos tablas
          ->join('answers', 'users.id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->where('answers.user_id', 3) // opcional
          ->limit(2)
          ->get();

      dd(json_decode($subsLists)); // Convierto el objeto en un array
 }
```

El array se vería de esa  forma:

```html
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#383 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"uuid": "91746cf7-6a48-48d8-8ea4-eab08298b425",
    +"created_at": "2020-09-01T23:16:00.000000Z",
    +"updated_at": "2020-09-01T23:16:00.000000Z"
  }
  1 => {#384 ▼
    +"id": 2
    + "uuid": "91746d1a-9d88-41b6-9216-ca1dedb38d9e",
    +"created_at": "2020-09-01T23:16:00.000000Z",
    +"updated_at": "2020-09-01T23:16:00.000000Z"
  }
]
```

La forma en como generas el resultado a la vista ya queda a tu gusto, lo puedes hacer en el controlador o lo retornas a la vista en un:

```
return view('vista', compact('consulta'));
```

Y el objeto lo recorres con un foreach en el blade o lo puedes hacer en el controlador como gustes, pero ya  en la variable consultas tendrías un objeto que a mi modo de trabajar es más manipulable, sin embargó también en el código tienes la opción para convertir a array con un `json_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

Si trabajas con modelos no es necesario recorrer y armarlos

**Modelo Form**

```
...
public function formanswer(){
    $this->hasMany('Clase','FK','PK');
}
...
```

**Consulta**

```
Form::with('formanswer')->find($id);

//res

{
  'name':'name',
  'formanswer':[
  {
      'uuid':'asdasd-asdasd-asdas-asdasd',
  },
  ]
}
```

En caso de que lo quieras como lista debes usar `get()`

```
Form::with('formanswer')->where('id',$id)->get();

//res

[{'formanswer':[]}]
```

**Mejorando tu consulta**

```
$formIds = [1,2];
Form::with('formanswer')->whereIn('id',$formIds)->get();
```

Pero si de todas formas quieres armarlo recorriendo las listas

```
    $formIds = ['1','2'];

    $formAnswersArray = [];

    foreach ($formIds as $formId) {
        $form = Form::find($formId);// si es ID se puede usar el método find()
        $formAnswers = FormAnswer::where('form_id',$formId)->get();
        $answersArray = [];
        foreach ($formAnswers as $formAnswer) {
            $answers['uuid'] = $formAnswer->uuid;
            $answers['created_at'] = $formAnswer->created_at;
            $answers['updated_at'] = $formAnswer->updated_at;
            array_push($answersArray ,$answers);
        }       
        $formArray = [
            'name' => $form->name,
            'answers' => $answersArray
        ];
        array_push($formAnswersArray,$formArray);

    }
```